# Can't connect to local SQL Server DB with connection string, but VS can

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a local Sql Server 2012 database instance trough Visual Studio 15 using connection string. While I've been able to connect to the DB through the Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer and run a test procedure successfully, I'm unable to do so in my project using connection string.

Here's my connection string that was given by the SQL Server Object Explorer

```
<connectionStrings>    
  <add name="objConnLocal" 
connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOPIVO;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=tnk;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Here's my code that works perfectly fine connecting to an Azure DB with Azure given connection string (the code works)

```
public class DbConn
{

public static string DatabaseConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["objConnLocal"].ConnectionString;
    public static SqlConnection objConn = new sqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString);



public void spCMSSelectTest(out DataSet ds)
{
    ds = new DataSet("buttons");
    SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCMSSelectTest", DbConn.objConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
}
```

And this is the DB I'm trying to connect to: [image]

Here's the test Page I'm trying to access:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds;
    try
    { 
    dbc.spCMSSelectTest(out ds);

        lblTest.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception easd)
    {
        lblTest.Text = easd.ToString();
    }

}
```

I've been going trough answers here and on google but nothing seemed to work for me. What Am I missing?

EDIT: 
There's the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   DbConn.spCMSSelectTest(DataSet& ds) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CMS\App_Code\DbConn.cs:line 22 at
>   index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CMS\index2.aspx.cs:line 18
>   ClientConnectionId:d576fae4-db3d-451d-8436-2abe003c01f0 Error
>   Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

Comment: What error do you get on connection?

Comment: None. I try to access a page, that only calls the above procedure and outputs the result to a label, when I try to open the page /localhost/cms/index2.aspx It returns me to /localhost/ and shows me the blue IIS default page

Comment: that doesnt sound like a sql connection issue that sounds like an iis issue

Comment: It errors when I try to openConnection(cmd);

Comment: but you just said it didnt error.... what is the error

Comment: Well I tried commenting the procedure and uncomment it line by line. up untill the openConnection it would give me System.IndexOutOfRangeException  Cannot find table 0. naturally there is no table 0 yet. When i unncommented the openCOnnection it would send me back to the iis homescreen (/localhost/) Added the test page I'm running to my answer

Comment: What does openConnection do? Im guessing something is erroring - but your code isnt reporting it back

Comment: Now we're talking!!! it tries to cmd.Connection.Open(); I'm getting a proper error now, adding it to the answer in a second. It's supposed to use WIndows Authentication though...

Comment: Well there you go, you're trying to log in with trusted connection but its running in a default pool not as a username... which apparently has no rights to log in to sql - you need to log in as "you" or "an sql user"

Comment: Would you like to post an answer so I can accept and up-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're logging in as a trusted user (default) - and that user is the pool user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool you need to either login as you, or an SQL login. As its not using the same credentials when running under a pool as it is from your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the database.

Add `Initial Catalog=tnk` to your connection string.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention it, I tried it and it didn't work. Tried both *tnk* and *master*, as my DataBase name is tnk. Updated my Question to include the Catalog in it.

Comment: Ok. Are you getting an error? Have you tried running the stored proc that you reference in SSMS to see what result you get? Also wrap your code in a try-catch, and see what detail you get if an exception is thrown.

Comment: I don't get an error, it just returns me to the blue iis home screen when I try to access a test page that only calls the above procedure. It fails to openConnection(cmd);